# Is there a way to view the console of CruiseControl.NET remotely?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, output, output-redirect

Is there a way to remotely view the terminal output of CruiseControl.NET remotely? At present, I am running the following command using an instance of Git Bash on the terminal log file located over a Windows share:

```
tail -f <filename>
```

This somewhat works (and is really nice in conjunction with using "grep -v" to filter out unwanted lines from the output), but the terminal updates new output slowly and sometimes misses new lines written to the console output file. Is there a plugin or built in way to hook into ccnet and remotely view the console output without having to monitor a file over a Windows share?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you could take a look at log4net appenders, since CCNet uses this logging library to write output to file, and it's configuarable through config file (respectfully for service or console).

There are many different appenders in log4net:
https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.html

Hopefully one of them will be suited better for your needs (I can't recommend any, haven't used much log4net..)

Comment: I always wondered what that Log4Net dll was in the CCNET directory, haha. I'll take a look at this and see if there is anything I can do with it.